# Timed rotating file logs

Tags: python, logging, configuration

I'm trying to make my python app create a different log file everyday at midnight but it keeps failing, the app overwrite old log files and it doesn't follow the rules about naming or timing.

Here's my logging config:

```
handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('/logs/Synclog.log', when="midnight", interval=1, encoding='utf8',atTime=time(0,0,0))
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Is there something wrong I'm missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure it overwrites the old log files? It does rename the file for the old logs, so you should look at a file named `Synclog.log.1` for yesterdays logs.

Comment: Yes, it does the rollover and creates the backup file of old log but keeps writing on both new log file and old one, and in the old one erases old info.

Later it stops writing on it, and only uses the new log file. But still I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a problem with gunicorn configuration and not with the code, The app was running 3 times and it was making logs going crazy.

Thanks anyway!